# Error when making directory

Tags: php, html

I'm new to PHP and I'm trying to create a directory (for a user) and I get a 500 Error when the script is launched.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        chdir("users");
        mkdir($_POST["username"]);
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: "A 500 error" could be caused by anything.  If you get a 500 error, that means there is a more descriptive error message somewhere in your web server's error log.  You need to look there to find out more.

Comment: A `500 Internal Error` HTTP response usually means a syntax error in the PHP code. The exact error message can be found on your server in a file usually named `php-errors.log` but this exact location depends on the local configuration. The posted code looks valid, though.

Comment: Your $_POST may not be set, you should wrap it in an `if(empty($_POST["username"]) { ... }` I'd also recommend you escape the variable to void yourself of running any malicious code on the server, never trust user input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error log will usually have a more detailed error message.  I'd guess it's permissions though.

Make sure your web service is allowed to create directories in the "user" dir.

Comment: this should be posted as a comment, not an answer

Comment: I gave him what's likely to be the answer.   Honestly I don't know why I'm taking exception to this particular comment as it happens on every goddamn stack post.

idaf about the point system. I honestly only come on when things are slow at work.  my response addresses his issue so I'm not sure why you think it should be a comment.

Comment: It was a permissions problem, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

first of all your problem can be caused by a huge amount of reasons so you need to narrow those down: turn error reporting ON.

Seccond, use the full, absolute path to create a directory so you don't get lost in your OS.

This way you can find out what the problem is, try this:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Login</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    mkdir(/home/$_POST["username"]);
  ?>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem here is that th3 user folder doesn't have www-data as user or group, and then write permissions. You should lookup these things and set them if they aren't correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty bad practice to make a directory like that, but to answer your question you probably need to check and make sure you have that variable first, before you try to work with it. Like this.

```
if(isset($_POST["username"])){
        mkdir($_POST["username"]);
}
```

The reason being that variable in the post isn't always there, its only there when you populate it, typically by submitting a form